# Why TeamViewer does not work through httpproxy in Linux environment?

Tags: linux, teamviewer

Why does TeamViewer not work with httpproxy in a Linux environment ?
I have verified the same httpproxy in Windows environment it works perfectly fine.
How different is Teamviewer in a Linux environment?

Comment: You might want to give some indication, at least, about why it doesn't work.  Do you get errors, have you checked through log files, etc.  You're going to need to give more detail.

Comment: TeamViewer is actually exactly the same in Linux... because it runs under Wine :-/

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by "httpproxy"? I presume you're either talking about the environmental variable `http_proxy` or you're talking about an actual proxy server acting either transparently or explicitly configured within TeamViewer. I'll address all three scenarios:

- **Environmental Variable:** Either you haven't set your environmental variable correctly (I see you refer to it as `httpproxy`, where in fact it should be `http_proxy` or TeamViewer isn't connecting via plain HTTP, in which case you should also make sure your `https_proxy` variable has been set correctly.
- **Explicitly Set Proxy:** Within TeamViewer it's possible to explicitly set an HTTP proxy under "Advanced Settings". I can confirm that if your proxy is correctly configured, TeamViewer does work successfully, as per personal experience. Either you haven't specified the proxy server within TeamViewer, or you've set it up incorrectly.
- **Transparent Proxy:** If your proxy is correctly setup server-side, TeamViewer does work successfully through a transparent proxy.

I suggest taking a look under "Advanced Options" within TeamViewer and setting your proxy manually.